# What are the advantages of using <table><tr> and <td> instead of the new CSS3 display; table?

Tags: html, css

I understand that one advantage may be that `<table>` works in older browsers but I still see many sites using `<table><tr>` and `<td>` when I would expect them to have switched. I refer to new sites like the very latest Microsoft Azure portal.  This site makes heavy use of latest CSS but still uses `<table>.`

Are there other reasons to use `<table>` other than for backward compatability?

Comment: `<table>` elements are still semantically correct way to present _tabular data_.

Comment: IE8+ supports it. Lots of people don't even support IE8 anymore.

Comment: `<table>` tag carries some semantic information. `<div>` doesn't. Technically speaking, HTML(5) allows to create any layout using only `<div>` elements plus CSS. For some reason HTML5 introduced dozens of semantic elements and saved `<table>` which is both semantic and layout.

Comment: Don't think of  a table as a way to align things, think of it as markup for tabular data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must not think about backwards compatibility in this scenario. Using `<table>` is still necessary even the CSS display `table` exist as the `<table>` element is used for Accessibility API for screen readers and indicates that anything inside of it is a tabular data. CSS display `table` just do only layout instructions to look like a table and nothing more than that.

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/